# Would a highly reflecting body orbiting near the Sun eventualy rise its temperature and be melted?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, temperature, thermal-radiation, dissipation

Would a highly reflecting body orbiting near the Sun eventualy rise its temperature and be melted even though it would start emitting radiation itself due to increase of its temperature if the backside(not illuminated by the Sun) is a perfect emitting black body? Also, the interior of the object should be of material that transfers heat very fast.

Comment: Voted to close because this depends on many factors, including the ability of the "backside" to radiate energy and the true reflectivity of the front side, which for physical materials is always less than exactly 1 .

Comment: @CarlWitthoft What is the result of the refl.side slowly absorbing and the black side dissipating? Will the black side dissipation hold the temperature at a maximum constant level?

Comment: the material needs to transfer heat away from the absorbing side fast enough to keep the temperature below the melting point, so thermal coefficients come into play, and then the back side has to radiate as much energy as is received to avoid thermal runaway

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Let say copper is used for the 'internal' material...if the absorbtion rate is constant but the dissipation not because depends on object temperature there should be a temperature of equilibrium between shiny part absorption and the back black part dissipation so the object should survive?

Comment: Is the object made of thorium oxide?

Answer (score 4):

The process of a perfect reflection is the absorption of a photon and reradiation with the same energy (that is the momentum and frequency). Although during absorption of electron, the material does gain some energy, but it is quickly lost when the photon is reradiated. The time taken in these events comprising of reflection is very less, and to some approximation can be considered *instantaneous* . The object will not gain energy, as it will reflect it, for rise in temperature unless some wavelengths or some part of incident radiation spectrum is being absorbed (as conventional mirrors absorb infrared and heat up). If it does absorb some of the incident radiation, it will start heating up and its back side will start emitting radiation or start melting as per its material's nature.

Comment: Nothing is "instantaneous" . What matters is (assuming an absolutely perfect reflector, which doesn't exist) that every incident photon is reradiated  AND that the momentum imparted to the object (think solar sail) is somehow not dissipated in any way.   The object as a hole MUST gain energy due to momentum conservation.

Comment: Perhaps I have misused the word "instantaneous", I was trying to convey the answer in a approximate approach. I too am well aware of the events a photon goes through in reflection. It was just to state the time taken for a photon to be absorbed and reradiated is very very less and would not cause increase in temperature of some perfect reflector. Anyway, thanks for pointing out. I will be giving out more elaborate answers from now on.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft the answer may be more acceptable now.

Comment: thanks,  removed downvote

Comment: I keep objecting to the absorption+reradiation narrative.

Comment: "the same energy (that is the momentum and frequency)" This is a non-sequitur. Also, a mirror does not reflect at the same momentum, as that requires transparency.